Links not working in angular 18 app with ssg
I have a very simple website built with angular 18 and want to use SSG. I have set it all up and ng build does generate all the necessary files. The only thing not working is the links from on part of the website to another.
The HTML for the links look like this for example:
 <a class="text-color group-hover:text-[#F1C203]" [routerLink]="['about']">About</a>

Then in the generated file after building it looks like this:
 <a _ngcontent-ng-c2439168922 class="text-color group-hover:text-[#F1C203]" href="./about">About</a>

But instead of the value for href being ./about I need it to be
./about/index.html.
How do I do that?
Fyi, I am providing the builder with a routes.txt file which has, for example, the 'about' route defined as /about.
In my app.module.ts. I have defined the routes like this
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
])

In my angular.json under build I have SSG enabled like this:
"server": "src/main.server.ts",
"prerender": {
  "routesFile": "routes.txt"
},
"ssr": false


Most web servers will redirect ./about to ./about/index.html. So no need to point there directly. Why do you need the HTML to point there? Also, checkout https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16051
